# Is it possible to display only debug messages from ssh?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to display only debug messages from ssh command like:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
```

And filter warning messages like:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added 'hostname' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

There is an option '-q' that disables warnings messages, bug it disables all debug messages as well.

Can I have one and not have the other?

Answer (score 1):

All the debug messages start with string `debug{1,2,3}`, so you can do this simply using grep, for example like this (note that these messages are on stderr):

```
ssh -vvv host 2>&1 | grep "^debug[123]"
```

but it will of course filter out also your password and shell prompt and other important messages. If you want to filter it into some file, it can work like this:

```
ssh -vvv host 2>&1 | tee >(grep "^debug[123]" > file)
```